# Can someone simply explain the definition of an Integral Domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Simply typing this question into google, I get:

An integral domain is a commutative ring with an identity (1 0) with no zero-divisors. That is ab = 0 a = 0 or b = 0.

I don't understand what they mean by an 'identity (1 0)' with no 'zero-divisors'

What exactly is an integral domain then in layman's terms

I'm currently trying to show Z{i} (the Gaussian integers) is an integral domain, and I've just shown Z{i} is a subring of C. So any help specific to this would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the page Google links.  It says $1\neq 0$, i.e., the (multiplicative) identity cannot be the additive one.  The Gaussian integers are NOT a subring of the integers.

Comment: It appears you are reading [this page](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/MT4517/Lectures/L4.html) and your browser is not rendering the unequal sign. It should be "with an identity $\,(1\ne 0)\ $ ..."

Comment: The $(1 0)$ part is just a Google mistranslation. It should be $1 \neq 0$. And definition you wrote says exactly what having no zero-divisors means: that if $ab = 0$, then either $a = 0$ or $b = 0$.

Comment: How exactly is $\Bbb Z[i]$ a subring of $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: I'm reading, and I'm not sure what the notation Z6 means... it goes on to say 2.3=0 if that helps. I've seen it before but can't remember

Comment: Did you not find helpful the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain) on integral domains?

Comment: Sorry about the mistake stating  Z[i] a subring of Z, the second Z was meant to be a C, and I've corrected this.

Comment: I'm now understanding how to prove it has no zero divisors. However, I'm not understanding the part where it says the identity 1 'not equal to' 0

Answer (score 1):

A zero divisor is a number that divides zero. More specifically, an element $a$ in a ring $R$ is a zero divisor if there exists some other element $b\neq 0$ such that $ab = 0$. For instance, in the ring of integers mod $4$, the number $2$ is a zero divisor since $2\cdot 2 \equiv 0$.

An integral domain is a ring without zero divisors.

A field is an integral domain where every nonzero element has an inverse.